# How to return only the length of an array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a program where tasks get done in "batches". The top-level view of my documents look like this:

```js
{
  _id: "xxx",
  status: "done",
  startedAt: 123456,
  finishedAt: 789101112,
  tasks: [...] // Huge array of deeply nested objects
}
```

Is it possible to construct a query for mongodb that returns only the length of the `tasks` array in this example?

Desired result:

```js
{
  _id: "xxx",
  status: "done",
  startedAt: 123456,
  finishedAt: 789101112,
  numTasks: 9999
}
```

Thank you in advance for any advice you can give.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$size`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      numTasks: {
        "$size": "$tasks"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zs7c6LP_ifv)**

Comment: Spot on! Thank you for your advice. And thanks for the mongo playground link, this is gonna be a huge help in the future!